# Modify Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've recently been developing on the django platform and have stumbled upon Django Forms (`forms.Form`/`forms.ModelForm`) as ways of creating `<form>` html.

Now, this is brilliant for quick stuff but what I'm trying to do is a little bit more complicated. Consider a `DateField` - my current form has fields for day, month and year and constructs a python date object from that. However, a django form creates a single textbox in which the correct format (say `2010-06-15`) must be entered. As another example, for large fields I need to replace `<input>` with `<textarea>`.

I'd like to take advantage of Django's forms for simple validation but I need something simpler for my users. So my question is: can I intercept the rendering of one of these objects to write out the html as I like? If so, do I have to do all the writing myself or can I only do those objects I wish to re-write?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

You just have to override the default widget that gets rendered for the field.
Look [in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets) for all the necessary information.

You can also define custom widgets if the necessity arises, e.g. a date field rendered with dropdowns instead of a single text field.

Google for them, there are already some pretty nifty widgets out there :)

Comment: Aaaah, thankyou! Knew it shouldn't be too difficult to do... just couldn't find it for looking.